# How to get my WhatsApp password?

Tags: python, passwords, whatsapp

I am writing web service in python to work with WhatsApp. I am using pywhatsapp library for that. But can anyone tell me how to get my WhatsApp password? It is needed for Login using pywhatsapp.

Hours of searching in Google didn't give any result.

Comment: As far as i know, your password is autogenerated by mobile device and therefore bound to your device. but this knowledge is 3 years old.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [yowsup cli](https://github.com/tgalal/yowsup/wiki/yowsup-cli-2.0#yowsup-cli-registration) to register a new WhatsApp user. During this process you will get a new password. Just download the cli and follow the instructions under [yowsup cli](https://github.com/tgalal/yowsup/wiki/yowsup-cli-2.0#yowsup-cli-registration).

You should also be able to reregister your own mobile number if it has already been used with WhatsApp. (e.g. on your phone)